# Want data from multiple rasters, but only for given points

Tags: arcgis-10.0

Working in ArcMap 10, I have a number of raster layers that are derived from a DEM (terrain attributes, some zonal statistics layers, flow accumulations).  I have a point layer that contains about 25 points that correspond to features I am interested in on the landscape.  As an early step, I would like to pull data from each of the raster layers, but I am only interested in the raster values that correspond to each of the points from my point shapefile.  Essentially I want to make a big table that lists many attributes (elevations, stream power index, flow accumulation, etc.) for each of the 25 points so that I can try to determine if there are relevant trends amongst the 25 points.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is super easy, assuming you have the Spatial Analyst extension. Use [Extract Multi Values to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002s000000):

> Extracts cell values at locations specified in a point feature class
>   from one or more rasters, and records the values to the attribute
>   table of the point feature class.

This is just a modified version of [Extract Values to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Extract_Values_to_Points/009z0000002t000000/) that's designed to work with multiple rasters.

Note that both of these tools modify the point feature in-place and do not create a new point feature class as output. So you may want to copy your point feature class ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks!  I do have Spacial Analyst, so this will be a breeze.  That's exactly what I want; I always assume these things are possible, but I can never figure it out on my own... much appreciated

Comment: I keep getting an error message (Error 999999). I'm extracting about 60 .tiff files (climate data) to feature class data in a file geodatabase. I need the feature data to be in a .gdb because the attribute names of the .tiff files are very long (aprx. 20 - 30 characters). When I run Extract Multi Values to Points, it creates new columns for the 1st four rasters and fails. However, the 1st 4 extractions are all null value. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: @SoilSciGuy First thing to do is isolate the problem: attribute table vs. number of rasters. To that end, do you get the same error when running Extract Multi Values to Points with two of your .tiff files?

Comment: I managed to get it working in batch mode. Not sure what the problem was. Thanks for the reply.